Queueable callout error - uncommitted work pending
I have a queueable apex class that is supposed to create records (dml), and after those records are created successfully - send them to 3rd party system.
When I'm running the test class, I get the following error message:
You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
I saw that moving the callout to a future method is recommended, but here I'm working already with queueable so it's impossible.
Also, I cannot change the sequence of the operations, because I need to create the records first (which can be a few hundred), and only after those records are created (partial insert), I need to send them to the 3rd party system.
How can this be achieved ?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Seeing your test class would help. This is one situation where it may be better to go through System.enqueueJob() than it is to directly call execute().

Hi Derek, thanks for the response. The question here is also about the process itself, I'm not concerned about the test class but whether this process is going to work at all. Also, in my test class, I'm calling the class that triggers the queueable using System.enqueueJob()

You can make the callout in a separate transaction:
public class MyClass implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
  Account[] records;
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    if(records != null) {
      ExampleCode.doCallout(records);
    } else {
      records = ExampleCode.createRecords();
      System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
  }
}

As far as the unit test, you'll want to do something like this:
MyClass ex = new MyClass();
Test.startTest();
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ExampleCode.CalloutMock());
// Don't use System.enqueueJob here, because we only get 1.
ex.execute(null);
Test.stopTest();
// At this point, the callouts should have occurred

Note that ExampleCode is just a placeholder for whatever it is you're actually doing.

Hi sfdcfox, thanks for the answer. So if the callout logic will be on a separate queueable class and I'll enqueue it once the first queueable job is completed - it should work ?

@Omnia You can either use the same queueable (as demonstrated here), or a separate one, whichever you prefer. It should work either way. It's just that unit testing is a little more challenging, since you only get 1 Queueable in a test.

Hi @sfdcfox, I tried to separate and created a new queueable that makes the callout. I'm getting now an error message which says Maximum stack depth has been reached. Do you have any idea why this error appears ?
